# why my Google plus og:description is not showing description

Tags: php

I am working on this website here and google plus sharing button just won't share the description. I have meta tags. I can't find anything wron. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really appreciate the help.

```
My meta tags

<?  if($_GET['Id']!="") {$det=$job_line['job_description']; $str=filter_var($det,   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://rozgaarexpress.com/beta/job-details.php?Id=259" /> 
<meta property="og:app_id" content="785624518149590" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$job_line['job_title'];?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$str?>" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://rozgaarexpress.com/images/facebooks.jpg" /> <? } ?>
```

please kindly check the url http://rozgaarexpress.com/job-details.php?Id=258

```
Thank you!
```

Comment: There are restrictions on the image-size. Did you try the facebook-debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?

Comment: Yes i try it in the facebook-debugger but not scraped the image

Comment: Did it say anything like `image too small, taking x`?

Comment: no sir you can also checkout link http://rozgaarexpress.com/job-details.php?Id=259

Comment: It scrapes an image, is this the wrong one?

Comment: Thanks for giving time for me now image is scrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot access to this image, try to check if it is public - http://rozgaarexpress.com/images/facebooks.jpg